# How to make json connecting in login form of android?

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

I am using json.php
in that written like:

```
<?php
 $mysqli_print = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'include', 'db_kanalytics_v2');
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }


    $result = $mysqli_print->query("select c_name,c_password from tb_cnt_user") or die($mysqli_print->error.__LINE__);

    if($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo json_encode($row);
        } 
    }

    else
    { }
?>
```

I want to make login page(In android ) for by taking values from mysql databease and from table "tb_cnt_user" .c_name,c_password are the column names of respective table.
please provide me code which i can include in my MainActivity.java file.

Thanks in advance..!

Comment: Where is the code that receive data from either POST or GET?

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand your question. What I understood was that you want to create a login form that connects to your php. If that's the case, you need to have a block that receive the POST requests or GET requests from your client and validate the user and echo a success message. Or if it's the opposite and you want to create a web login. You simply create a web page that POST to your php and again, your php will validate the user and echo success message. Then you can show your web form with a web view on android, make a web client and check if the contents after the POST is success.

Comment: Either way you need a code block that receives data in your php.

Comment: My guess is that he/she wants to download the credentials and check them on the client side.